# How to check for differentiability of function of several variables by using definition of differentiability?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Show that $F(x,y)= \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

In order to do so, i have to arrive at contradiction in the definition. That is, 
$df=f(h,k)-f(0,0)=Ah+Bk+h¥+k₩$ where $A$ is first order partial derivative with respect to $x$ and $B$ is with respect to $y$. And $¥,₩$ are functions in $(h,k)$ which tend to zero as $(h,k)$ tend to zero.

Now, i arrived at $1=\sin\theta+\cos\theta$.
But how should i contradict this last statement? (Coz this is valid for $\theta=0$, 90°)

Also, how to conclude that a function is differentiable through this definition?

Comment: anyway, to show a two-dimensional limit fails, it suffices to show one path approaching the limit point fails. You might as well focus on a coordinate path like (x,0) for which $F$ restricts to $|x|$ (oops strike my previous comment, it's a kink not a vertical tangent)

Comment: @James S. Cook I want to know through this particular method, using definition of differentiability.

Comment: How are you going to use this definition when the partial derivatives that you need for it don’t exist?

Comment: @amd this comment is somehow the mathematical analog of when Agent Smith asks Neo how he is going to speak when he has no mouth.

Comment: Something feels off about your definition of differentiability. Splitting the error into two functions seems like an unnecessary complication.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s look at what this definition means. For a function $f$ to be differentiable at the point $(x_0,y_0)$, we can find two real numbers $A$ and $B$ such that the change in $f$’s value near that point, $\Delta f=f(x_0+h,y_0+k)-f(x_0,y_0)$ is approximated by $Ah+Bk$, with the error in this approximation vanishing “faster” than the displacement $(h,k)$.

Let’s apply this to $F:(x,y)\mapsto\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. The error in any linear approximation to $F$ at the origin is $$\phi(h,k)=\sqrt{h^2+k^2}-Ah-Bk.$$ Along the $x$-axis this error is: $$\phi(h,0)=\sqrt{h^2}-Ah=|h|-Ah.$$ For $h>0$, this is $(1-A)h$. By your definition, we must have $(1-A)\to0$ as $h\to 0$, but $A$ is a constant, so the only way this can happen is if $A=1$. On the other hand, for $h<0$, $$\phi(h,0)=-h-Ah=-(1+A)h=-2h$$ since we’ve already determined that $A$ must be $1$ to make the error along the positive $x$-axis vanish fast enough. Obviously, $-2$ does not tend to zero. We can’t even find a value of $A$ that will produce a small enough error along the $x$-axis only, so there’s no hope of finding $A$ and $B$ that will work everywhere around the origin.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $F$ were differentiable at $(0,0)$ then $\partial F/ \partial x(0,0)$ would exist. But $F(x,0) = |x|.$